# How to Block Iframe call

Tags: .htaccess, iframe

Recently my complete site is called in iframe by two other domains. I would like to block other sites, who are trying to show my site in iframe.

How can i block that through .htaccess?

Answer (score 68):

You can set the variable in the header X-Frame-Options: Deny.

All modern browsers support the X-Frame-Options header.

The Facebook uses this header to disable iframe/framesets (also Javascript).

If you have enabled the mod_headers in apache:

.htaccess

```
Header set X-Frame-Options DENY
```

But, you can enable iframes come from the same origin.

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

Or in Nginx:

```
add_header X-Frame-Options Deny; #or SAMEORIGIN
```

Browser compatibility: [Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header)

- Internet Explorer: 8.0
- Firefox (Gecko): 3.6.9 (1.9.2.9)
- Opera: 10.50
- Safari: 4.0
- Chrome: 4.1.249.1042

Comment: i think, that this is the best way to do so. another appropriate way would be using php: header("X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN")... js or referrers are pointless

Comment: Note : The Header directive is in the mod_headers apache module. You need to make sure that module is loaded into the apache server.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/19510208/2042775

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can through .htaccess, you can use JS however. You can use a function like this one to check:

```
function parentIsSameOrigin()
{
    var result = true;
    if (window.parent)
    {
        result = Boolean
        (
            // more precise modifications needed here
            window.this.location.href.indexOf(window.parent.location.href) == 0
        );
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Mmm...but what if JavaScript is disabled on the client's browser?

Comment: There is no other way, if this is a legitimate concern I would load the contents of the Iframe using JS to ensure nothing displays unless the function validates.

Comment: You can always put display:none with css and remove it with javascript. It forces not to display content if user has disabled javascript (which is unacceptable for modern standards).

Answer (score 2):

You can't "enforce" it per-say since there are ways around, but you can use the standard header method. [html5-boilerplate](https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess#L405) has a nice vhost/htaccess snippet that first sets `X-Frame-Options` as your choice of `DENY/SAMEORIGIN/ALLOW-FROM`, and then allows whitelist MIME types for use in good frames such as Google image search.

Check the link for latest, but here is the example from Jan 25 2016 in `SAMEORIGIN` mode:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

     Header set X-Frame-Options "SAMEORIGIN"

     <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
         Header unset X-Frame-Options
     </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use .htaccess as the following

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=[^&]+ [NC]
# if referrer is bad.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (www\.)?bad\.com [NC]
# then redirect to a different page
RewriteRule !^404.shtm [L,NC,R=302]
```

You will need to rely on HTTP_REFERER for this this code will redirect any requests from the bad.com to the not found page

this solution contributed to this answer

https://stackoverflow.com/a/19773719/1641233

Answer (score -4):

Umm, I don't think you can.

An iframe is a client side container, which means that the end users browser is responsible for loading the content within the iframe.  You wouldn't be able to tell the difference between whether your page was loaded in an iframe or not.

Comment: This is not true. You can check via JavaScript that if the webpage is `top`. `window.top === window`.