# Internal Server Error from htaccess caused by Invalid command 'Header'

Tags: .htaccess, wamp

I have a htaccess file that it work perfectly on host but when I put it on local ,it shows me this error:

> Internal Server Error
>
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was
>   unable to complete your request.
>
> Please contact the server administrator, admin@localhost and inform
>   them of the time the error occurred, and anything you might have done
>   that may have caused the error.
>
> More information about this error may be available in the server error
>   log.

I found this alert in error log file :

> [Tue Apr 17 10:02:25 2012] [alert] [client 127.0.0.1] D:/wamp/www/jivan/sql/.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

this is my htaccess file code:

```
  RewriteEngine On
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/keyword_show.html$ keyword_show.php?keyword_id=$1
RewriteRule ^page_(.*).html$  page.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/(.*)/(.*)/(.*).html$ $2.php?advertisement_cat=$1&id=$3&pagenumber=$4
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/(.*)/(.*).html$ $2.php?advertisement_cat=$1&pagenumber=$3
RewriteRule ^([0-9-]+)/(.*).html$ $2.php?advertisement_cat=$1
# cache images and flash content for one month
<FilesMatch ".(flv|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico|swf)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>

# cache text, css, and javascript files for one month
<FilesMatch ".(js|css|pdf|txt)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000"
</FilesMatch>
```

my local server run by wamp and I enabled rewrite module too!!!

so what`s the prob?!!

Answer (score 134, accepted):

the `Header` directive is in the `mod_headers` apache module.  You need to make sure that module is loaded into the apache server.

Answer (score 109):

Steps to enable HEADERS modules

```sh
$ cd /etc/apache2/mods-available
$ sudo a2enmod headers
$ /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
```

Comment: This can be a one-liner: `sudo a2enmod headers && sudo service apache2 restart` (should work on Debian-based distros).

Answer (score 36):

On your command line:

Install mod_headers

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

and then restart apache

```
service apache2 restart
```

Answer (score 12):

Try this:

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c> Header set [your_options] </IfModule>
```

Have you restarted WAMP after installing / enabling?

Answer (score 6):

In an Ubuntu/Debian Machine you can simply run this command:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/apache2/mods-available/headers.load /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/
```

and should be all set.....

Answer (score 3):

If you are using WAMP server, do the following

1. Left click on Wamp tray icon.
2. Go to Apache -> Apache Modules.
3. Enable 'headers_module' from the list of modules.
4. Restart the wamp server or Restart All Services.