# Access-Control-Allow-Origin: 500 Internal Error

Tags: php, apache, osx-mountain-lion, mod-headers

So I am trying to have siteA do a jquery .load of some content on siteB.  In doing this, im getting the Access-Control-Allow-Origin Error.  So on siteB, I placed a .htaccess file that should allow siteA to be able to grab content from it.  I am running into some trouble with this.  I know the .htaccess file is being access because it is getting a 500 Internal Error when the page tries to load and i have content in the .htaccess file.

In the .htaccess file i have tried: 
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
and: 
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: "*"

but both give the 500 error.  I have also tried:
    
    Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *

This doesn't give the 500 error, so it must be coming back as false.  I am not really sure what to do at this point.  its possible i might be formatting the .htaccess file wrong or something, but i think it may have to do with mod_headers not being enabled.

In Logs:
    Invalid command 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin:', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Both sites are running through 10.8 Server.app, so its a little different from a normal Apache install which is making it a little difficult.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!  Thanks in advance!

Comment: `500` can mean your `.htaccess` is bad.

Comment: I don't think Access-Control-Allow-Origin is causing your 500 errors. Check your server error logs to see what the reason for the 500 is.

Comment: just added the log to the orig question.  When i comment out the Access-Control command, the site loads, when it is uncommented, it errors.  That line is the only line in the .htaccess

Comment: "Invalid command Access-Control-Allow-Origin" would lead me that you have the wrong syntax in the .htaccess file. Can you post the .htaccess file with the header line included?

Comment: Sorry, first .htaccess file i have done.  I didn't know i needed a header.  The commands i had above was all the text from inside the .htaccess file.  I just changed it to "Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"" and i think that is working now. Not seeing the errors anymore. Thanks for the help Steven!!

Answer (score 11):

I was just having the same issue, error 500 when I used:

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

It was due to a missing module , mod_headers , I just had to run on my server:

```
sudo a2enmod headers
```

as found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185717/internal-server-error-htaccess)

but i think you may need to edit manually .conf on  OSX and uncomment the line:

```
#LoadModule headers_module modules/mod_headers.so
```

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I have copied code from somewhere, which is having some spaces, that was the reason for internal server error.

I was using

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin : *");
```

We should write

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin:*");
```

I have just removed spaces between Origin, :, and *

Try writing the code instead of copy, that may help.

Comment: Specially the gap should not between "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" and ":"