# Getting error while running my application using PHP and codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting the following error while running my application in my server.

> **Error**:
>
> Internal Server Error
> The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.
> Please contact the server administrator at webmaster@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you
> performed just before this error.
> More information about this error may be available in the server error log.

When I checked the error log file I found the following error message.

```
.htaccess: Invalid command 'Header', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
```

In my `.htaccess` file I am using the `Header` like below.

```
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf)$">
 Header set Cache-Control "max-age=604800, public"
</FilesMatch>
```

Please help me to resolve this error.

Comment: Did you enable apache `mod_headers` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10185717/internal-server-error-htaccess