# How can I make my website not be displayed in iframes

Tags: php, html, .htaccess

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Block Iframe call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881139/how-to-block-iframe-call)

I want my website not to be displayed in iframes.

How can I do it?

Comment: Please provide some example code as to what you're currently doing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881139/how-to-block-iframe-call

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to your htaccess or server config:

```
Header always append X-Frame-Options SAMEORIGIN
```

It will prevent (at least in browsers that support it) your site from being displayed inside *another website's* iFrame.

Comment: This is something I have never encountered nor thought to implement. I guess you do learn something new every day!

Comment: @Matt if you learned something today, it would be good to upvote the answer no?

Comment: @HasanKhan point well taken, sir. +1 up in this piece!