# Rewrite requests to website from specific domain name with .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How do I rewrite all requests from a specific domain name to my site with .htaccess?

For example, if `http://www.example.com` had a link to my site, then I want to redirect them to a different page on my site, but other links from other websites and direct links should display the requested page like normal.

I've been getting in a muddle with how to do this... Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE:**

Some information as requested in an answer:

My stripped down .htaccess file looks like this:

```
# irrelevant all squashed together (issue still remains when used like this)
 <Files .htaccess>
  order allow,deny
  deny from all
 </Files>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions MaxRedirects=10
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301]
ErrorDocument 400 /error.html
ErrorDocument 401 /error.html
ErrorDocument 403 /error.html
ErrorDocument 404 /error.html
ErrorDocument 500 /error.html
Options All -Indexes
IndexIgnore *
LimitRequestBody 10240000

#redirect
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} ^http://(www\.)?badsite\.com/ [NC] 
 RewriteRule !^error\.html /error.html [L,NC,R=302]
```

The header of the page I am visiting looks like this:

```
Referer: http://www.badsite.com/wiki/Page
```

**2nd UPDATE:**

The intended actions are:

1. Visit `http://www.example.com/wiki/Page`
2. Click on link to `http://www.mysite.co.uk/thispage/here`
3. Because of the `example.com`, I should be redirected to `http://www.mysite.co.uk/badpage` instead of `http://www.mysite.co.uk/thispage/here` like all other requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to rely on HTTP_REFERER for this. Put this code in your sub-directory's `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^id=[^&]+ [NC]
# if referrer is bad.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (www\.)?bad\.com [NC]
# then redirect to a different page
RewriteRule !^start start [L,NC,R=302]
```

Though remember that `HTTP_REFERER` can be spoofed and is not 100% reliable.

*PS: It turned out to be unique situtation due to dokuwiki installation*

Comment: That is very similar, maybe even the same to what I tried, but it does not work. I don't know why. There must be something odd going on with my .htaccess file but I'm having trouble working out what.

Comment: You should post your complete .htaccess in your question for investigation.

Comment: Done that, could you possibly take a look and see if there is anything glaringly obvious wrong?

Comment: For some unknown reason, this still does not work. I have never had an issue with .htaccess in the past. I have allowed access to the .htaccess file now and I visited `http://www.mysite.co.uk/.htaccess` and it shows the same code as you have written.

Comment: Is `.htaccess` even enabled? Try putting some garbage text on top and see if you get 500 error OR not.

Comment: Yep that works fine. All other rules I have (like external and internal redirections for 'clean' URL's) work fine. It is odd that this does not work, especially as the header matches the URL. I am of course changing the domain to the correct one, but the theory should still work and I really don't understand why it doesn't.

Comment: With a changed condition, can you try: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} (www\.)?badsite\.com [NC]`

Comment: That doesn't work either. Is there any other HTTP header variables that we could include that we might maybe have more luck with? I can't think of any, but you seem more knowledgeable than I am! Also, do you know if theres any way of disabling what we are trying to do? Because if there is, we can try and enable it, but again I don't know anything about this.

Comment: Unfortunately other than HTTP_REFERER there is not other header variable that can tell you whether link is coming from a bad site.

Comment: I can't think of anything we can do then. How odd :/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40525/discussion-between-anubhava-and-jason)