# .htaccess allow deny in iframe for domain

Tags: php, .htaccess

i try code in *.htaccess* deny allow not work in *iframe* server apache 2.4

```
<Files "iframe.php">
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from xxxx.com
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
    Allow from xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa
    </Files>
```

or

```
    <Files "lihat.php">
    require all denied
    require host nontonindramaonline.com
    require ip 168.235.82.232
    </Files>
```

show in iframe **xxxx.com/iframe.html**

```
Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /iframe.php on this server.
```

please help me and???

Comment: Well, access is only allowed for `xxxx.com`, `127.0.0.1` and `xxx.yyy.zzz.aaa`. Everyone else will get a 403 Forbidden.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Block Iframe call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881139/how-to-block-iframe-call)