# How to block my website from loading in other sites iframes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, iframe

How do I block my website from an iframe? For Instance YouTube cannot appear in a iframe it will say in place the owner of this website have blocked iframes. i am aware of the meta  tag way like this

```
    <meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="deny">
```

howerver that does not work for me, is there any other way, i would prefer to use javascript and html no apachi php ajex or others please. this is the youtube iframe that i wish to block just with my site. also without .htaccess

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>YouTube</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe width="50%" height="50%" src="http://www.youtube.com" >
</iframe>
</body>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Block Iframe call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5881139/how-to-block-iframe-call)

Comment: Its not a duplicate i dont want the .htaccess way either.

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5881184/3892581) from that question includes a javascript solution!

Comment: @Hodrobond  The answer to that question didnt work, the answer from my did work

Comment: @MohammadHamedani The answer to that question didnt work, the answer from my did work, and...Its not a duplicate i dont want the .htaccess way either.

Comment: Please consider not to downvote i did not do a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to put in `head` or `body` tag

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function PreventFrame() {
    try {
        if (window.top !== window.self) {
            document.write = "";
            window.top.location = window.self.location;
            setTimeout(function() {
                document.body.innerHTML = '';
            }, 0);
            window.self.onload = function() {
                document.body.innerHTML = '';
            };
        }
    } catch (err) {}
}
PreventFrame();
</script>
```